# Can't find my exported .apk file after exporting. why is that?

Tags: android, export, apk

I just exported my first Android app. the process went fine, including signing procedure. however, it seems I cant locate the file. If I try to go through the process again, it says the file already exists (and indeed I can view it using the "browse" options in the exporter wizard). But when I look for it in the windows explorer window, its just not there. its not "hidden" either. It's just invisible.

It's weird because I can't locate the file in the windows explorer, but it *is* visible with the "browse" thing, only at the exporting wizard!

Does anyone know why? How can I reach my file?

Comment: I don't understand. What is the path that you're saving your file? It's the last step in the Export Application wizard.

Comment: i saved it at the path of C:\. i am looking in the right place, its just not visible via the 'windows explorer' window.

Comment: i will post pictures showing what i mean, would be the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What IDE are you using ? If you use Eclipse, the .apk must be in the folder YourProjectFolder/bin

Comment: fml im a retard. cant believe i didnt search there. it is there.

Comment: however, can you explain the thing in the pictures? why is that not visible?

Comment: now im trying to compile and sign again (it seems i did it with the debug key...) and it doesnt give the apk file at all. no output. anywhere. where can it be? im going crazy.

Comment: Just try building it to a location where you can easily find it, like (a folder on ) your desktop.

Comment: Exactly! The Wizard allows you to select a place in the export.

Comment: that's the thing. when i did it before, it didnt even create the file anywhere (even search didnt find it via windows search). now it puts it at the assigned place. i guess it was some random bug. thanks for replies people :)